# iOS: Over The Air distribution works on iPad1 (iOS 5) but not on iPad3 (iOS 6)

Tags: ios, distribution, enterprise, over-the-air

I'm trying to setup over the air distribution for an enterprise inhouse app. For testing i have an iPad 1 with iOS 5 and an iPad 3 with iOS 6. The server from which i try to install the ipa is within our company network, and the ipads connect to this network with the VPN client.

The application runs on both iPads when installed using the iPhone Configuration Utility. But Over The Air installation works only on the iPad 1. On the iPad 3, when clicking the download link, i get the message

```
"Cannot connect to Mysubdomain.myserver.com"
```

When I check the serverlog after downloading from the iPad 1, i see this log:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2012-11-01 12:59:49
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2012-11-01 12:59:49 172.16.50.30 GET /sp_for_ipad/download.html - 80 - 172.16.127.177 Mozilla/5.0+(iPad;+CPU+OS+5_0_1+like+Mac+OS+X)+AppleWebKit/534.46+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/5.1+Mobile/9A405+Safari/7534.48.3 200 0 0 890
2012-11-01 12:59:52 172.16.50.30 GET /sp_for_ipad/manifest.plist - 80 - 172.16.127.177 iTunes-iPad/5.0.1+(32GB) 200 0 0 78
2012-11-01 12:59:55 172.16.50.30 GET /sp_for_ipad/image.57x57.png - 80 - 172.16.127.177 iTunes-iPad/5.0.1+(32GB) 200 0 0 31
2012-11-01 12:59:56 172.16.50.30 HEAD /sp_for_ipad/MyApp.ipa - 80 - 172.16.127.177 iTunes-iPad/5.0.1+(32GB) 200 0 0 109
2012-11-01 12:59:56 172.16.50.30 GET /sp_for_ipad/image.512x512.png - 80 - 172.16.127.177 iTunes-iPad/5.0.1+(32GB) 200 0 0 31
2012-11-01 13:04:45 172.16.50.30 GET /sp_for_ipad/MyApp.ipa - 80 - 172.16.127.177 iTunes-iPad/5.0.1+(32GB) 200 0 0 288293
```

When I try to download from the iPad3, this is all I see in the serverlog:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2012-11-01 12:59:49
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2012-11-01 13:04:00 172.16.50.30 GET /sp_for_ipad/download.html - 80 - 172.16.127.179 Mozilla/5.0+(iPad;+CPU+OS+6_0+like+Mac+OS+X)+AppleWebKit/536.26+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/6.0+Mobile/10A403+Safari/8536.25 200 0 0 62
```

So, it doesn't even query for the manifest.plist.

my download.html looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://Mysubdomain.myserver.com/sp_for_ipad/manifest.plist">Install App</a>
</body>
</html>
```

So - the link seems to work for the iPad 1, but not on the iPad 3. I've setup the MIME types on the server correctly.

The strange thing is - I also tested the whole procedure with another server which is not within the company VPN (so I then don't use the VPN clients on the iPads) and in this case the installation works with both iPads. But now I don't know - is there maybe some significant difference with the server?

or is the problem connected to the fact that access goes through the VPN?

Why does it work on iPad1 but not on iPad3 - is there anything different in iOS6 that could cause the problem?

Does the download link need to look differently for iOS6 devices?

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this problem? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I wrote this yesterday and no, so far I did not come up with a solution. Are you also inside a VPN? Does it also work for you for iPad1 but not on iPad3? or does it work for you on iOS 5 but not on iOS 6?

Comment: Im not inside a VPN but im having the same issue of it working in iOS 5 but not iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you might try eliminating the display-image and full-size-image keys.  Maybe it's an issue with retina image sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar, though no VPN, just a plain Wi-Fi setup.
iPhone4, iPhone5 and iPad2 all running iOS6 can install OTA with no issues.
At the same time, iPhone4S and iPad1 running iOS5 fail to install the app OTA.
Normal installation via iTunes sync works fine for all devices.
It's obviously an issue with OS version, but I have no idea where to look for next.
Is it in the build settings for the app or something related to server config (IIS in this case)...